# How many objects can I construct with given number of items

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics

I have a number of ingredients and must know the maximum number of sandwiches (Big and small sandwiches) I can make with it. If ingredients remain, the result must be false.

- Big sandwich : 4 slices of tomatoes and 2 slices of cheese
- Small sandwich : 2 slices of tomatoes and 1 of cheese

My code works if all ingredients can be used with only small sandwiches or maximum one big sandwich.
It also returns false if ingredients are remaining.
However, it returns false if we need more than one big sandwich in order to use all ingredients.

```js
var result = []
var ispossible = function(tomatoes, cheese) {

  /* we need in any case an even number of tomatoes slices */
  if (tomatoes % 2 === 0) {
    /* the easiest way is making as many small sandwiches as possible. The minimum number of big sandwiches is the number of cheese slices remaining when we devise the total number by 2  */
    var bigSandwich = cheese % 2
    var smallSandwichTomatoes = (tomatoes - 4 * bigSandwich) / 2
    var smallSandwich = cheese - bigSandwich
    console.log("we need" + smallSandwich + "small sandwiches and " + bigSandwich + "big sandwiches")
  } else {
    console.log("false, all the ingredients cannot be used")
  }
}

ispossible(10, 3)
```

Comment: Small sandwiches are exactly half of big ones, so why should big ones even be considered? You can just calculate the number of small sandwiches. Also, this is clearly your homework - StackOverflow is not really the right platform for this. Maybe give Reddit r/learnprogramming a shot.

Comment: To the OP, it's perfectly fine for the question to come from homework, and it's a decently formed question (well organized, clear, including your attempt).  It could be improved by adding your theory of what's going wrong. (or @MauriceNino, do I have this wrong?  Do we care if a well-asked question came from homework?)

Comment: The statement "*they both have the same amount of cheese*" is directly contradictory to the statements in your question, in which each type of sandwich is described with differing quantities of cheese: "*Big sandwich : 4 slices of tomatoes and 2 slices of cheese;
Small sandwich : 2 slices of tomatoes and 1 of cheese*". Can you clarify?

Comment: Obviously it is a home work question, But yea, you will have to follow the greedy approach, So you should make sure that there are max Big Sandwiches made, And then move on to the smallest. Also the approach is fine, just needs some more tuning, Also some more Math is required to calculate. Did you debug and check regarding the result ?

Comment: What constitutes the "*maximum number of sandwiches*", exactly? Since 1 small sandwich's ingredients are exactly 1/2 that of a large sandwich, why wouldn't the answer be just to return the number of small sandwiches you can make with the given ingredients (assuming the number of tomatoes is even and there is exactly half that quantity in cheese)? In this scenario, any algorithm which generates any quantity of large sandwiches > 1 would be incorrect, no? Why would it be an issue if "*[your] code works if all ingredients can be used with only small sandwiches or maximum one big sandwich*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this solution helps other readers with enhancing their rudimentary algorithm, programming skills:

```
const bigSmallSandwiches = (t = 10, c = 5) => (
  t % 2 !== 0 || t / c !== 2 ?
  'false, all the ingredients cannot be used' :
  'we need ' + Math.floor((t - Math.floor(t / 4) * 4) / 2).toString() + ' small sandwiches and ' + Math.floor(t / 4).toString() + ' big sandwiches'
);
```

**Explanation**

1. If number of tomato slices is not 'even' or if number of cheese is not exactly half the number of tomato, return 'false'.
2. Determine number of 'bigSandwiches' as tomatoes / 4
3. Determine number of 'smallSandwiches' using remaining slices of tomatoes

Code-snippet:

```js
const bigSmallSandwiches = (t = 10, c = 5) => (
  t % 2 !== 0 || t / c !== 2 ?
  'false, all the ingredients cannot be used' :
  'we need ' + Math.floor((t - Math.floor(t / 4) * 4) / 2).toString() + ' small sandwiches and ' + Math.floor(t / 4).toString() + ' big sandwiches'
);

[
  [20, 10],
  [8, 4],
  [4, 3],
  [14, 7]
].forEach(x => console.log('tomatoes: ' + x[0] + '\tcheese slices ' + x[1] + '\n' + bigSmallSandwiches(x[0], x[1])));
```

Comment: `Math.floor(t/4)` gives the largest number of big-sandwiches that may be prepared with 't' slices of tomatoes. So, if t = 20, then 5 big-sandwiches; and t = 14, then 3 big-sandwiches. `(t - Math.floor(t/4) * 4)` gives the remaining slices after accounting for big-sandwiches. Half this gives the maximum number of small-sandwiches possible. Anyone who needs more help, please feel free to ask specific info.

Comment: Wouldn't we prefer to make 10 small sandwiches (not fewer big ones) from 20 tomatoes and 10 cheeses?   I think this is a good answer to a different question (one that tries to *minimize* sandwich count).  I wonder if the OP has a typo.

Comment: Correct or not, I don't think **any** beginner would look at this code and understand what's going on. Maybe you should use variables to make it clear what you are doing.

Comment: @danh, Come to think about it, 1 big-sandwich uses tomatoes & cheese exactly same as 2 small-sandwiches. So, I'm now wondering (when trying to maximize) if there'll ever be a situation where one will need to make any big-sandwich at all.

Comment: Just to clarify, the solution is not specifically targeted for any **beginner**. As noted in the solution, the assumption is that it _helps other readers_.